# I have 507 resources in your service. CloudFormation has a hard limit of 500 resources in a service. For advice on avoiding

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-serverless, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

CloudFormation has a hard limit of 500 resources in a aws service.bu i have using 507 resources that error will be occurs so how to overcome the error. i want to be increased the limit using serverless node.js @node.js,@aws,@serverless,@dynamodb.

1. I want to increase the hard limit as 500 resources but My resources as 507 its have been above the limit.
2. I'm using serverless node.js at aws service as dynamodb,SNS,S3 Bucket,SES email to the services used into the my project.
3. Its cross the limit so what i do if anyone knows the fix this issues.Please help me to answer this issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS documentation already has solution for your problem, you should visit this page - [AWS CloudFormation quotas](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cloudformation-limits.html).
This documentations mentions about:

> To specify more resources, separate your template into multiple templates by using, for example, [nested stack](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-stack.html).

Hope this is solution to your problem.

Comment: thank you hi its correct and i want next requirement as delete the resource from the stack have any package or any services in aws ???

Comment: If you want to delete object from stack, just adjust the template, and run it again.

Comment: What you might to want to read about as well is change sets - when you modify template, and try to run it, it would indiacte you what operation is going to be run on your resources

Comment: Dynamodb ,s3bucket and SES, SNS  here i don't want to delete the resource .I'm just remove the resource in the template

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell if you're using Serverless Framework or not, but if that is the case, you can take advantage of dedicated plugin that will automatically split your resources into multiple stacks to get around this limitation: https://github.com/dougmoscrop/serverless-plugin-split-stacks